# T does not contains a defination for particular method

Tags: c#, generics

I have two classes. One is Parser class and another is Demo class (i.e Generic class). Parser class has a method to parse i.e. 'MyParserMethod', which I want to used in 'Demo' class. But, I think it is not practice untill I define that 'T' is a parser class type. Currently, 'MyParserMethod' not accessible in Demo class. What to do to use it in Demo class ?

```
public class Demo<T> : IDemo 
{
    private T _parser;
    public Demo(T objParserClass)
    {
        _parser = objParserClass;
    }

    public void GetParseValue()
    {
        Dictionary<int,string> _Collection = new Dictionary<int,string>();
        _Collection  = _parser.MyParsingMethod(); // Error here.
    }
}
```

Comment: `T` always  will be `Parser`?

Comment: Looks like your `Demo` class don't have to be generic.

Comment: Just discuss first before make any one point minus. If T always be parser then I will define it using where close. But the problem is that T always not be a particular parser class. Currently , If I used xyzParser, in future I may be use abcParser class.

Answer (score 4):

The solution is to limit `T`

```
public class Demo<T> : IDemo where T : IParser
{
    // ...
}

public interface IParser
{
    Dictionary<int,string> MyParsingMethod();
}

public class Test : IParser
{
    // ...
}
```

Then you can use it as follows:

```
Demo<Test> instance = new Demo<Test>(new Test());
```

Comment: Yes, I was trying something like this, I will try again it and let you know if I stuck somewhere, thanks..!!

Answer (score 0):

use where clause in order to say that this T is at least your Parser class and maybe its decedent

```
Public class Demo<T> : IDemo 
where T:Parser
{
   //...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Don't use generics if you don't need to and just pass a Parser instance into your Demo class instead. However, if you are going to have various Parser implementations then use a 'where' clause on the generic method as follows:

```
Public class Demo<T> : IDemo where T : Parser
{
    ...
```

Comment: I can't fixed T as a Parser because It may be used another parser in upcoming future. I don't want to do any change in Demo in future when I switch parser to xyzParser

Comment: So abstract Parser into IParser or ParserBase that contains your parsing method and have all your parsers implement/derive accordingly and use this abstract in your generic type constraint.